# sending a file through a curl command or postman

Tags: python, curl, flask

sending a file through a curl command or postman

I am trying to upload image to my Flask app, I was able to sucesffuly do that through a web browser upload button, however when I do a POST request from my postman if it giving me a error 303

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2017-03-28 20:16:05] "POST /api/user/uploadimg/ HTTP/1.1" 302 632 0.005147
```

here is my Flask code

```
@app.route('/api/user/uploadimg/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload_file():
    def allowed_file(filename):
        return '.' in filename and \
            filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    # check if the post request has the file part

    if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return jsonify({"Nope":"No file entered"})
    file = request.files['file']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        user=User.query.get(7)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        user.image_filename=filename
        user.image_url=url_for(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({"Done":"All set!"})
    return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload new File</title>
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>'''
```

I would love to know how can I curl the following url and send the file using a curl or postman. 
 PS: I have postman sending the  command as POST method, and the content type is multipart-data

Here is the curl command I am using to send data

```
curl -X POST -F "file=certificate.pdf" http://localhost:3500/api/user/uploadimg/ -H "Content-Type: multiform/form-data"
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, in postman when sending multiform data, the value for Content type does not have to be specified. I have no idea how to do it with curl command.